# Javascript Navigation Menu

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how I can modify certain parts of my javascript to act a certain way. Currently, I have a webpage that is a gallery. Clicking on nav menu brings out a list of projects I have done. Clicking on the project brings up the big image in the background. However, I want to implement on one of my navs, specifically the website nav, to also open a new window with the website I built so people can peruse it. Here's the section of my script so far:

```
//clicking on a thumb, replaces the large image
            $list.find('.st_thumbs img').bind('click',function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                $loader.show();
                $('<img class="st_preview"/>').load(function(){
                    var $this = $(this);
                    var $currImage = $('#st_main').children('img:first');
                    $this.insertBefore($currImage);
                    hideThumbs(); ///hides thumb after image click
                    $loader.hide();
                    $currImage.fadeOut(2000,function(){
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                }).attr('src',$this.attr('alt'));
            }).bind('mouseenter',function(){
                $(this).stop().animate({'opacity':'1'});
            }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
                $(this).stop().animate({'opacity':'0.7'});

            });
```

I would try this, but it doesn't recognize the link. So I am thinking it has to be the javascript.

```
<li class="album">
        <span class="st_link">Websites<span class="st_arrow_down"></span></span>
        <div class="st_wrapper st_thumbs_wrapper">
        <div class="st_thumbs">

                <img src="images/album/thumbs/web1.jpg" alt="images/album/web1.jpg"/>
                <a href="www.tannerhuynh.com/starbuzz/home.html"><img src="images/album/thumbs/web2.jpg" alt="images/album/web2.jpg"/></a>
  </div>
</div>
</li>
```

The website is www.tannerhuynh.com and I was hoping clicking on the thumb would not only load the background image but bring me to website I built at www.tannerhuynh.com/starbuzz/home.html

I'm new to javascript and I haven't the slightest clue how to do this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Tanner

Comment: your a href should have http:// in front of it.

Comment: Omg, wow.... I can't believe the smallest change makes a big difference... It works!!!!!! Thanks a lot!! I also added a target="_blank" to make it open up a new window.

Comment: No prob.. i added it as an answer. You may also be able to do it via window.open("http://www.link.com") after your click event.  If the answer resolved your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html a(href="www) is incorrect.  It should look like:  a(href="http://www.website.com").  As you stated in the comments, that solved your solution.